# Simple regular expression question

Tags: regex

I basically want to learn how to extract a number from between 2 words...

For example I want '2000' from the phrase 'around 2000 years'.

How would I do this?

Cheers

Comment: When asking [tag:regex] questions, it is helpful to mention/tag which language/flavor you're asking about.

Comment: @joe, you should accept some more of your questions. (As I see you've gotten plenty of good answers.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this regex:

```
\b[0-9]+\b
```

Comment: Does `\d` match more than `[0-9]`? i.e. `\b\d+\b`

Comment: `\d` is just a shorthand for `[0-9]` so it should yield the same result.

Comment: Cool, thought so but wasn't entirely sure! Thanks.

Comment: @Kevin, depends on the flavor/language/unicode support/character set modifiers/etc. Eg, in Perl `\d` could some times mean: *"all the characters that are decimal digits somewhere in the world will match `\d` ; this is hundreds, not 10, possible matches."*

Answer (score 2):

the syntax could differ depending on your language

```
/([0-9].*)/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> re.compile('\\b[\d]+\\b').search('around 2000 years').group()
'2000'
```